# How to select the name and address of all users with birth dates after 1970 and before 1990

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble getting the users with birth dates after 1970 and before 1990 but because date_of_birth is not formatted as date I am having some trouble.

user (email, password, name, date_of_birth, address, type)
primary key(email)

I have written this query:

```
select name, address
from user
where str_to_date(`date_of_birth`, '%m/%d/%Y') > str_to_date('1,1,70', '%m/%d/%Y')
and str_to_date(`date_of_birth`, '%m/%d/%Y') < str_to_date('1,1,90', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

However, this return query return no results but in the user table I can see users that were born between those dates

Comment: constant `1,1,70` not matching with format string `%m/%d/%Y`, it gets NULL

Comment: Why are you using an `AND` instead of `BETWEEN date1 AND date2`? And why are your dates strings in the first place, instead of being DATE values?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just learning sql and this was my first time actually working on one that I did not know that it could be date values

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dates in your table are in a similar format to the dates shown in your sample code, your format string for `STR_TO_DATE()` is entirely inappropriate.

You could use `str_to_date('1,1,16', '%c,%e,%y')` - note the different format codes for month, day, and year, and the commas to match your format.

The MySQL manual for [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) has a complete list of format codes

Once you've got the date right you can go further:

```
select name, address
from user
where str_to_date(`date_of_birth`, '%c,%e,%y') between '1970-01-02' and '1989-12-31'
```

Note: `BETWEEN` includes the endpoints, so I've adjusted the dates to match your test.

So many questions about MySQL date handling start by fixing the date format. I recommend you update your schema to store dates in MySQL `DATE` or `DATETIME` columns